# AsyncFileUpload is not working properly

Tags: c#, jquery, asyncfileupload

I am getting problem with AsyncFileUpload.
**First problem is on page load it shows error message in Mozilla :**

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete.

Script: url.../CreateUserQuiz.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.5.60623.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3aen-US%3a834c499a-b613-438c-a778-d32ab4976134%3ade1feab2%3af9cec9bc%3ae4bd8421%3a62b503f2%3a35576c48:12
```

**And Second problem is after selecting file, It loads whole page, does not upload image and generates new url as below** :

```
url.../CreateUserQuiz.aspx?AsyncFileUploadID=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_uploadImage&rnd=09863899940190336<br><Br>
```

Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply CssClass on ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload like "clsAsyncUpload" in your aspx page.

And put the following code at top of your aspx page:

```
<style>
    .clsAsyncUpload input
    {
        width: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
```